# Tic-Tac-Toe game board pieces are being shifted between turns

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a simple python tic tac toe game.

My issue is that the X's and O's move between turns

Example

```
Tic Tac Toe
This is a 2 player game.
 
What is player one's name:A
Hi  Alfred
What is player two's name:B
Hi  Aiden
Press enter to start.

-  |  -  |  -
------------
-  |  -  |  -
------------
-  |  -  | -
It is Alfred's turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:1
O  |  -  |  -
------------
-  |  -  |  -
------------
-  |  -  | -
It is Aiden's turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:4
O  |  -  |  -
------------
X  |  -  |  -
------------
-  |  -  | -
It is Alfred's turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:2
O  |  O  |  -
------------
-  |  X  |  -
------------
-  |  -  | -
It is Aiden's turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:
```

Here is my code currently:

```
# Intro
print('Tic Tac Toe')
print('This is a 2 player game.')

print(' ')
player1 = input('What is player one\'s name:')
print('Hi ', player1)
player2 = input('What is player two\'s name:')
print('Hi ', player2)
print('Press enter to start.')
input()

# Board
board=['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-']
player1_win_condition_1 = ['X', 'X', 'X','-', '-', '-','-', '-', '-']
player1_win_condition_2 = ['O', 'O', 'O','-', '-', '-','-', '-', '-']
# Display Board
def display_board():

    print(board[0], ' | ', board[1], ' | ', board[2])

    print('------------')

    print(board[3], ' | ', board[4], ' | ', board[5])

    print('------------')

    print(board[6], ' | ', board[7], ' | ' + board[8])





# Handle Turn
def player1_play():
    while True:
        while True:
            player1_move = int(input("It is "+ player1 + "'s turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:"))
            if player1_move == (1):
                break
            if player1_move == (2):
                break
            if player1_move == (3):
                break
            if player1_move == (4):
                break
            if player1_move == (5):
                break
            if player1_move == (6):
                break
            if player1_move == (7):
                break
            if player1_move == (8):
                break
            if player1_move == (9):
                break
            else:
                print('Please chose a number from 1 to 9.')
        graph_location = player1_move - 1
        if board[graph_location] == 'X' or board[graph_location] == 'O':
            print('Sorry that spot is taken.')
            pass
        else:
            board.insert(graph_location, 'O')
            display_board()
            break

    if board == player1_win_condition_1:
        print('Player ', player1, ' has won!' )
        print('The End!')
        quit()
    else:
        pass



def player2_play():
    while True:
        while True:
            player1_move = int(input("It is "+ player2 + "'s turn choose a number from 1 - 9 to mark the grid:"))
            if player1_move == (1):
                break
            if player1_move == (2):
                break
            if player1_move == (3):
                break
            if player1_move == (4):
                break
            if player1_move == (5):
                break
            if player1_move == (6):
                break
            if player1_move == (7):
                break
            if player1_move == (8):
                break
            if player1_move == (9):
                break
            else:
                print('Please chose a number from 1 to 9.')
        graph_location = player1_move - 1
        if board[graph_location] == 'X' or board[graph_location] == 'O':
            print('Sorry that spot is taken.')
            pass
        else:
            board.insert(graph_location, 'X')
            display_board()
            break

    if board == player1_win_condition_2  :
        print('Player ', player1, ' has won!' )
        print('The End!')
        quit()
    else:
        pass




#def handle_turn():
#player1_move =
#player2_move =

# Check Win
#   Check Rows
#   Check Columns
#   Check Diagonals
# Check Tie
# Change Players
# Play Game
def play_game():
    display_board()
    while True:
        player1_play()
        player2_play()


play_game()
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code [with  a debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)?

Comment: `board.insert` inserts a new cell in the list, which causes all following values to shift over by one.  i.e. your board is growing.

Comment: Unrelated: replace the `+` with `,` in your last call to `print` at the end of `display_board`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update the board, you're inserting a new value into the list with the insert(value, position) function.

```
    b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    # The following line puts 0 at the 1st position
    b.insert(0, 1) 
    # b is now [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Instead, you should index the list with [] operator, and assign a new value to it. This allows you to replace a value at a particular position.

```
    b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    b[2] = 5
    # b is now [0, 1, 5, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`board.insert` is not what you want. It adds new data into the list, making the list larger and "pushes" existing elements towards the end, after the inserted element. You're not seeing this because your display board function only shows elements 0-8.

Instead, you want lines like

```
board[graph_location] = marker
```

Comment: Thanks helps a lot. Also to determine who wins should I use win conditions like i did above or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that `insert` add the string and not replacing it.
use `[]` instead:

```
board[graph_location] = 'O'
board[graph_location] = 'X'
```

not:

```
board.insert(graph_location, 'O')
board.insert(graph_location, 'X')
```

Answer (score 0):

in the `else` part, instead of:

```
else:
            board.insert(graph_location, 'O')
```

change it to:

```
else:
            board[graph_location] = 'O'
```

also, do the same thing for the 'X' part.
I hope it helps.

**suggestion**:
you can clear the screen by writing `\n` a couple of times before you display the board, it will be nicer to see.

```
# Display Board
def display_board():
    print('\n'*20) # <--- clear the screen 20 lines before displaying the board
    print(board[0], ' | ', board[1], ' | ', board[2])
    print('------------')
    print(board[3], ' | ', board[4], ' | ', board[5])
    print('------------')
    print(board[6], ' | ', board[7], ' | ' + board[8])
```

Comment: Ya thanks that works really good. Honestly forget you can do that lol.